# S3 Bucket + Microsoft Azure Blob Storage in magento 2

Tags: magento2, s3

Is any one has experience with Microsoft Azure with Magento2? Any one knows how Azure blob storage integration with Magento2. Any extension available?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are 6 modules developed for Magento 2 to achieve fully abstracted filesystem. You can use any one of them to achieve your goal.

Comment: could you please list those 6 modules?